# Touch events on subclass of UIView as a subview of UIScrollView

Tags: uiview, uiscrollview, touch

I have implemented my own custom subclass of `UIView` and overridden the `drawRect:` method.

In my custom view I also want the handle touches, so I also overridden `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded`.

This works fine but if the number of views on the screen increases then I have to use a `UIScrollView` as the root view of my `UIViewController`.

Once my custom `UIView` becomes the subview of `UIScrollView`, then it does not receive the touch events. Even though I move my finger within my custom `UIView`, the scroll view gets scrolled (all my touch events go to the `UIScrollView`).

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several approaches you could try:

1. Try setting the below properties on the `UIScrollView`:

   `scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;`
   `scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;`

   See similar SO questions/answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2588475/1367622), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725721/disallow-uiscrollview-from-catching-subviews-touches).
2. Implement `hitTest:withEvent:`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4629821/1367622), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2472188/1367622).
3. Use a `UIGestureRecognizer`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11951835/1367622), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11564934/1367622).

I would personally recommend using a `UIGestureRecognizer`, but it depends on your specific situation (any of these options may work fine for you).

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Adding delaysContentTouches makes scroll not works

Comment: I triedl first approach. This exactly what I wanted, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this response from another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4629821/193254

You'll have to subclass the scrollview too, and implement that `hitTest:` method.